# History of folder size

Tags: linux, disk-usage

Is there any way in Linux to track the changes of a specific folder's size over time? i.e let's say we created a folder `PHOTO` one year ago. Is there any way to see how the folder size changed over time?

Comment: It all depends on the filesystem which you use and meta data which are stored by it. Usually the answer is *no*.

Comment: This is probably possible with `auditd` if you're using RHEL. `auditd` can be configured to log system calls, which can include writing a file in a certain directory. That could be enough for you to get the size of a directory if you are using RHEL. http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/

Comment: best way should be to use some kind of front-end monitoring tool which will pick up your Linux command and create metric graphs in time e.g Nagios